# useState and localStorage in Next.js with SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

in the code below I'm keep getting this error: "localstorage is not defined"
I'm pretty sure this happens because next.js is trying to render the page on the server. I tried to put the `const [advancedMode, setAdvancedMode] = useState( localStorage.getItem("advancedMode") === "true" ? true : false );` inside useEffect but it does not work. Any idea?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

const Home = () => {
  const isMountedRef = useRef(null);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [advancedMode, setAdvancedMode] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("advancedMode") === "true" ? true : false
  );
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  
  // Some other code...
```

I have also tried the code below but then I get an error "advancedMode is not defined"

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const [advancedMode, setAdvancedMode] = useState(
      localStorage.getItem("advancedMode") === "true" ? true : false
    );
  } else {
    const [advancedMode, setAdvancedMode] = useState(false);
  }
```

Comment: Check if the code on server side if(window !== undefined) ...

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the localStorage, you need to check if you are on server or client. You can do so by checking type of window object.

```js
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  // You are on server
} else {
  // You are on client, and can access the localStorage
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but then I get another error, "advancedMode is not defined"

Comment: ok, i don't know what the advancedMode is. Sorry :(